# Missing key in map literal when returning value

Tags: go, go-gin

I am trying to show on html a json array but I need to put a name before the var:

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var mjson []model.Author
        db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@tcp(localhost)/bibliotecagnommo")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        datos, err2 := db.Query("SELECT * FROM author;")
        if err2 != nil {
            fmt.Println(err2)
        }
        for datos.Next() {
            var id, nombre, apellido string
            err3 := datos.Scan(&id, &nombre, &apellido)
            if err3 != nil {
                fmt.Println(err3)
            }
            autor := new(model.Author)
            autor.Id = id
            autor.FirstName = nombre
            autor.LastName = apellido

            //autorJsonString := string(autorJson);

            mjson = append(mjson, *autor)
        }
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
    //This line of code     "wordToAvoid":mjson,
        })
    })
    r.Run()

}
```

There is a way to avoid putting a word before that?

Because when I print the var on html it shows the word I putted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace

```
c.JSON(200, gin.H{
    //This line of code     "wordToAvoid":mjson,
        })
```

with

```
c.JSON(200, mjson)
```

NOTE: `gin.H` has type `map[string]interface{}`, so you need to pass a map 
 i.e. a key is mandatory there. But if you see, the method JSON accepts `int` and `interface{}`, so just pass an interface{} i.e. your object `mjson`.